# How to run a function in background?

Tags: function

I create a script, paste data in it, saving, executing, and delete:

```
vi ~/ms.sh && chmod +x ~/ms.sh && nohup ~/ms.sh && rm ~/ms.sh
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash

commands...

function myFunc {

commands...
}

myFunc ()
```

How could I properly run only `myFunc`, in the background, or alternatively, in another process? If it's even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a shell function pretty much anywhere you can use a program. Just remember that shell functions don't exist outside the scope in which they were created.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
f() {
    sleep 1
    echo "f: Hello from f() with args($*)" >&2
    sleep 1
    echo "f: Goodbye from f()" >&2
}

echo "Running f() in the foreground" >&2
f one

echo "Running f() in the background" >&2
f two &

echo "Just waiting" >&2
wait

echo "All done"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You run them in the background as in any other shell command or script with a `&` at the end.

Bash and similar shells also allow you to combine commands with `(` and `)` such as:

```
(command1; command2) &
```